# How to stream Audio from another android device

Tags: android, android-studio, url, socket.io, media-player

in android studio we have media player to play audio from local device or from url by using the method mPlayer.setDataSource(fileToPlay)  or  mPLayer.setDataSource(url)
now my question is how to play or stream audio from another device or you can say how to make url server in android device then you can access files in this device

tried to use socket.io class in android but unfortunately when i use media player with data source setting to be the ip address of the other device and port 8080 + the audio file location but it is giving error